# bin2dec error using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watermark

[image: original gray image][image: permuted halftone image]

Im doing a project where i need to use LSB watermarking technique to embed a halftoned permuted image to base original image. I found the below code while browsing through internet , but it throws below error while executing.

```
??? Error using ==> bin2dec
Binary string may consist only of characters 0 and 1

Error in ==> hi77 at 71
final = bin2dec(baseImage);
```

code:

```
wm_image = reshape(outImg(randperm(numel(outImg))),size(outImg)); % permuted watermark image.
figure;
imshow(wm_image);
[wm_row,wm_col]=size(wm_image);
wm = dec2bin(wm_image);
wmlength = wm_row*wm_col;
baseImagelength = row*col;
baseImage = dec2bin(inImg);% Original gray scale image
i=1;
j=1;
k=1;
counter=0; 
while i < baseImagelength
          counter=counter+1;
          if counter > wmlength
              break;
          end
          baseImage(i,8)=wm(j,k);
          k=k+1;
          if k>8
              k=1;
              j=j+1;
          end
          i=i+1;
  end
      key1=wm_row
      key2=wm_col
final = bin2dec(baseImage);
final = reshape(final,row,col);
img1(1:row,1:col)=final(1:row,1:col);
imshow(img1);
```

Please Help anyone with the above code.

Comment: try: when the error is thrown, type `baseImage` in the command window. What is there?

Comment: When I execute the code I get: "Undefined function or variable 'outImg'." So I guess the example is not really complete.

Comment: @Trilarion "outImg"-> permuted image and "inImg" gray image which i have not shown here in this code.

Comment: @Ander Biguri when i type "baseImage" it shows same binary values

Comment: @STripathy you should post the images you are using, that has to be the problem. Else it looks like the code is right. Can you post some link to the images you use?

Comment: @Ander Biguri i have shown the images which i have taken 1)original 2)halftoned permuted image